# How to format specific text in a vertical line inside .txt file?

Tags: c++, format

I've managed to write some random data between 1 and 10 to a file using this sample code:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
{
    type = rand () % 3;
    switch (type)
    {
    case 0:  afile << rand () % 10;
             break;
    case 1:  afile << rand () % 10;
             afile << "\t\t";
             afile << rand () % 10;
             break;
    case 2:  afile << rand () % 10;
             afile << "\t\t";
             afile << rand () % 10;
             afile << "\t\t";
             afile << rand () % 10;
    }

    afile << "\t\t" << "// Possible type " << i << endl;
}
```

My output look like this:

```
8       // Possible type 1
1       7       // Possible type 2
4       0       3       // Possible type 3
```

How can I format the comment to make it stay in a vertical line which look like this:

```
8                       // Possible type 1
1       7               // Possible type 2
4       0       3       // Possible type 3
```

I've tried `setw` with no success since I'm running a loop which makes `setw` inapplicable here. Is there any function that help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Why not just put some extra tabs in the `case` statements?

Comment: you are adding 2 tabulators between numbers ... but not when the numbers are missing ... add `"\t\t\t\t"` for case 0  and `"\t\t"` for case 1

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to update your `case` statement as follows:

```
switch (type)
{
case 0:  afile << rand () % 10;
         afile << "\t\t\t\t\t\t";
         break;
case 1:  afile << rand () % 10;
         afile << "\t\t";
         afile << rand () % 10;
         afile << "\t\t\t\t";
         break;
case 2:  afile << rand () % 10;
         afile << "\t\t";
         afile << rand () % 10;
         afile << "\t\t";
         afile << rand () % 10;
         afile << "\t\t";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is inside the switch statement right before the break:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    type = rand() % 3;
    switch (type)
    {
    case 0:  
        afile << rand() % 10;
        afile << "\t\t\t\t\t\t" << "// Possible type " << i << endl;
        break;
    case 1:  
        afile << rand() % 10 << "\t\t" << rand() % 10;
        afile << "\t\t\t\t" << "// Possible type " << i << endl;
        break;
    case 2:  
        afile << rand() % 10 << "\t\t" << rand() % 10 << "\t\t" << rand() % 10;
        afile << "\t\t" << "// Possible type " << i << endl;
    }
}
```